# Monitoring an applications performance within Visual studio

Tags: performance, monitoring, polling, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studios Community 2015 RC

I made a windows service that runs 24/7 and polls a FTP server for files in a specific directory, extracts the file, transforms the file, then sends the file to another ftp for further processing.

I guess I'm a bit paranoid of the cost of this polling and want to verify their is no increase in resource consuming over long periods of time.

How do you guys monitor performance? Do people typically test this with some sort of add on in the debugging phase within visual studio or wait until release with some sort of application?

Comment: *Visual Studio* is an IDE, and it doesn't seem you're trying to monitor the performance of the IDE. You probably should edit the title of your question to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Sure, you are liable to tick off the owner of that FTP server.  If you suddenly can't connect to it anymore then you know he did something about it.